# Swift, ¿Como continuar ejecutando código aun después de mandar la app a Background?

Tags: swift, background, task

Estoy muy perdido en eso, tengo una app que descarga archivos pero en cuanto se manda la app al "background" se cancela el proceso, me gustaría que esas descargas continuaran hasta finalizar, y no tengo idea de como lograrlo.

He visto publicaciones de otras personas que utilizan el "DidEnterBackground" para ejecutar código cuando la app entra en ese modo, pero no me gusta ese comportamiento, es decir, no quiero ejecutar algo hasta que se mande la app al backbround, en mi caso durante el uso de la app suelen ejecutarse esas tareas de actualización/descargas y solo quisiera que esas tareas no se detuvieran, simplemente continuaran como si la app estuviera en primer plano.

Trate de seguir esta documentación de apple:
[Using Background Tasks to Update Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app)

Pero me perdí aun mas.
Trate de registrar la tarea como lo menciona allí, pero siento que estoy ensuciando mucho mi código añadiendo cosas en otras zonas que no van.

Tengo una clase exclusiva para procesar peticiones al servidor, con unos métodos que descargan los archivos.

```
class ServerQueries{
    func checkNewFiles(){}
    func downloadFile(file){}

    func updateProccess(){
        let areNewFiles = checkNewFiles()
        for file in areNewFiles{
            downloadFile(file)
        }
    }
}
```

Esa es la clase que procesa las descargas y cada que se ingresa a un sección, la app revisa si hay nuevos archivos para esa sección y los descarga si fuera el caso. El problema que en cuanto el usuario manda la app al background, se interrumpe la descarga, y es lo que quiero evitar. Quiero lograr que el ciclo termine con toda la lista disponible.

(Editado)

Logre algunos segundos(30s) usando beginBackgroundTask pero no me son suficientes:

```
    self.identifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        print("Time End, incomplete download")
                                    
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.identifier!)
    })
    updateProccess()
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.identifier!)
```

He leído algunas publicaciones donde mencionan que ese proceso les suele dar minutos de tiempo en background, pero no veo diferencia en sus ejemplos, supongo que tiene que ver con mi algoritmo, donde realizo descargas individuales dentro de un ciclo:

```
for file in areNewFiles{
    downloadFile(fileName: file)
}
func downloadFile(fileName: String){
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        // Save downloaded file
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

pero es solo una suposición del motivo.